# how to attach to globle BeginRequest event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to handle the BeginRequest event in other functions like this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(MyBeginRequest));
    }
 ....
 }
```

But it didn't work!
Can someone tell me how?thx!

Comment: [Why can't my host (softsyshosting.com) support BeginRequest and EndRequest event handlers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123741/why-cant-my-host-softsyshosting-com-support-beginrequest-and-endrequest-event?rq=1)
In this question, I find it works in the init() function, but why not in the  Application_Start function??

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
     protected void Application_BeginRequest()
     {
        // do work
     }
 }
```

Comment: I know this, but I want to attach some new events dynamically.