# Best place to set CurrentCulture for multilingual ASP.NET WebAPI applications

Tags: asp.net, globalization, asp.net-web-api

based on this question ([Best place to set CurrentCulture for multilingual ASP.NET MVC web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226514/best-place-to-set-currentculture-for-multilingual-asp-net-mvc-web-applications)) I'm looking for a global way to do the same for ASP.NET WebAPI.

My current implementation for ASP.NET MVC looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new DefaultControllerFactory(new CultureAwareControllerActivator()));


    }
}


public class CultureAwareControllerActivator : System.Web.Mvc.IControllerActivator
{
    public System.Web.Mvc.IController Create(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType)
    {
        string cultureName = null;

        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null && requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ?
                      requestContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0] :  // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
                      null;

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = RoedingGmbh.Pis2Go.Web.Mvc.Helpers.CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        // Currently the UI Language is only english
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the same things as in ASP.NET MVC, but following code doesn't work properly.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
 {
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator), new CultureAwareHttpControllerActivator());

          }
 }


 public class CultureAwareHttpControllerActivator : System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator
 {
     public System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController Create(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
     {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("DE-de");
        return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(controllerType) as System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController;
     }
 }
```

With that code, WebAPI cannot find any route anymore :(
What have I to do to get this to work!

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want global localization for **whole application**, you can put the set culture code into the BeginRequest method of the HttpApplication in global asax file. This will set your culture in the most first place of **each** request and will affect every MVC and webapi request.

Comment: Your answer seems to be to easy, but it works like a charme. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: But what about threads using await/async? will this propagate through them all?

Comment: In the case the User.Identity is needed, it is better to use AuthenticateRequest, because on BeginRequest the User is not defined yet. Side note: I was not being able to set the event handler. This thread helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123741/why-cant-my-host-softsyshosting-com-support-beginrequest-and-endrequest-event

Comment: For async/await and since .Net Fx4.6, we are supposed to set [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture)/CurrentUICulture instead. They have both gained a setter, and setting them is supposed to work across async/await calls.  
But I cannot get it to work in my case. I set them in an ActionExecuting handler of an action filter, between two async calls. The controller action does see the change.

Comment: According to this [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384405/1178314), we have to do the switch way earlier, like in an authorization filter. What a mess.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a ActionFilter

If you are using Asp.Net MVC

```
//A foreigner, has possibly brew a cookie for me
public class SpeakNativeTongueAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    const string cookieName = "culture";

     void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookieKeys = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

        if (cookieKeys.Contains(cookieName))
        {
            //eat the cookie
            var theCultureCookie = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
            var theCulture = theCultureCookie.Value;

            //say thanks in native tongue
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(theCulture);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(theCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            //Didn't receive a cookie, don't speak their language, those bastards!

        }
    }
}
```

In Javascript you can set the language in a cookie named "culture"

Comment: //A foreigner, has possibly brew a cookie for me ?

Comment: We did this way at first, but it seems that the Model Binder is called *before* the Action Filter, so you might run into parsing issues. Global asax is best.